# Take screenshot of screen behind form?

Tags: c#, winforms, screen, screenshot, screen-capture

I am trying to take a screenshot with a form of a screen **BUT** I don't want my form to be included in the screenshot. This is my current Code for getting the screenshot.

```
Bitmap bt;
Graphics screenshot;
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = 0;
    bt = new Bitmap(Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds.Width, Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    screenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bt);
    screenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds.X, Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pictureBox1.Image = bt;
    this.Opacity = 1;
}
```

This works to a degree, but the problem is that when I do this it causes the screen to flicker each time. Is there any way to make it so it doesn't include my form, but still takes everything behind it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take a screenshot of what is behind your form, but you can hide you form, take a screen shot and show your form again. 
How to do this:

1. Hide your form
2. Wait some time until the screen has been repainted.
3. Take the screenshot.
4. Show your form.

You should make 2 asynchronous by using a Timer class.

Good luck with your task.

Comment: You sure there isn't anyway at all to achieve this? Because I have seen applications in the past that do something like this.

Comment: Also does this cause the form to flicker?

Comment: In the old days the computer generated the windows, now a days the windows are fully drawn to the graphic card and it stores the entire window even when only parts of the window is displayed, this is why windows 7 can show small previews of a hidden windows.  There is a possibility that you can generate a screenshot without hiding/changing opacity on your form, but I don't know how.